# Jquery find method vs traditional selectors

Tags: jquery

I have a div with an id - #calculator1

I want to target classes within that div - for example a class named key.
I am using a fictional method called "setToBlank()"

Out of the following methods- which would be considered best practice?

1: `$("#calculator1  key).setToBlank()`

or store id in cached variable-

```
_calculator = $("#calculator1");
_calculator.find("key").setToBlank();
```

I am using it repeatedly, so saving it in a cached variable is logical.
I am just not sure if .find is more inefficient as I would be calling it repeatedly.

Comment: I have to be honest... use either way and you/your users will **not** notice a difference. People get too hung up on performance and it always confuses be because 99% of the time, performance isn't what you should be worried about - maintainable code is. Which method makes more sense to you? I'd say use whichever you deem appropriate.

Comment: the best one for the situation depends on the situation. ***In this very specific case***, it's better to use .find due to how fast `$("#id")` is. http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-children-and-id-selector/10 there is no *general best practice*, it's going to depend from case to case. Do not worry over this kind of a vs b performance unless you actually have a performance problem. Even knowing that .find is faster, i would use the selector instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [Learn jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/performance/optimize-selectors/#id-based-selectors), version with `.find()` is faster:

> The .find() approach is faster because the first selection is handled
>   without going through the Sizzle selector engine – ID-only selections
>   are handled using document.getElementById(), which is extremely fast
>   because it is native to the browser.

Side note. `find("key")` searches for `key` tag. For class use `find(".key")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the efficiency of `.find()` versus jQuery selectors, but you have a bug in the code you posted.

```
$("#calculator1 key).setToBlank();
```

This will look for all key tags within #calculator1, you need to have it like this:

```
$("#calculator1 .key").setToBlank();
```

This will select all items with class key inside of `#calculator1`

Answer (score 0):

I think the most performative is:

```
var field =$(document.getElementById("calculator1"));
field.find("key").setToBlank();
```

if you want the tools to test the performance: http://jsperf.com/